# What type are my suffixes?

Tags: code-golf, string, sorting

### Intro

So I've been wasting my time again researching suffix sorting algorithms, evaluating new ideas by hand and in code. But I always struggle to remember the type of my suffixes! Can you tell me which type my suffixes are?

### Left-most what?

A lot of suffix sorting algorithms (SAIS, KA, my own daware) group suffixes into different types in order to sort them. There are two basic types: **S-type** and **L-type** suffixes. *S-type* suffixes are suffixes that are lexicographically less (**S**maller) than the following suffix and *L-type* if it is lexicographically greater (**L**arger). A *left-most S-type* (*LMS-type*) is just that: A *S-type* suffix that is preceeded by a *L-type* suffix.

The special thing about these *LMS-type* suffixes is that once we sorted them we can sorted all the other suffixes in linear time ! Isn't that awesome?

### The challenge

Given a string assume it is terminated by a special character that is less than any other character in that string (e.g. smaller than even the null byte). Output a type corrosponding char for each suffix.

You can freely choose which char to use for which type but I'd prefer `L, S and *` for `L-, S- and LMS-type` as long as they are all printable (`0x20 - 0x7E`).

### Example

Given the string `mmiissiissiippi` output (when using `L, S and *`):

```
 LL*SLL*SLL*SLLL
```

For example the first `L` is due to the fact that `mmiissiissiippi$` is lexicographically greater than `miissiissiippi$` (the `$` represents the added minimal character):

```
L - mmiissiissiippi$ > miissiissiippi$
L - miissiissiippi$  > iissiissiippi$
* - iissiissiippi$   < issiissiippi     and preceeded by L
S - issiissiippi$    < ssiissiippi$
L - ssiissiippi$     > siissiippi$
L - siissiippi$      > iissiippi$
* - iissiippi$       < issiippi$        and preceeded by L
S - issiippi$        < ssiippi$
L - ssiippi$         > siippi$
L - siippi$          > iippi$
* - iippi$           < ippi$            and preceeded by L
S - ippi$            < ppi$
L - ppi$             > pi$
L - pi$              > i$
L - i$               > $
```

Some more examples:

```
"hello world" -> "L*SSL*L*LLL"
"Hello World" -> "SSSSL*SSLLL"
"53Ab§%5qS"   -> "L*SSL*SLL"
```

### Goal

I'm not here to annoy Peter Cordes (I'm so gonna do this on stackoverflow sometime); I'm just very lazy so this is of course [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) ! The shortest answer in bytes wins.

---

Edit: The order of the chars is given by their byte value. That means compare should be like C's `strcmp`.

Edit2: Like stated in the comments output should be a single character for each input character. While I assumed that would be understood as "return a string" it seems at least 1 answer returns a list of single characters. In order to not invalidate the existing answers I will allow you to return a list of single characters (or integers which when printed result in only 1 char).

---

#### Tips for linear time:

1. It can be done in 2 parallel forward iterations or in a single backward iteration.
2. The state of each suffix depends only on the first 2 chars and the type of the second.
3. Scanning the input in reverse direction you can determine L or S like this: `$t=$c<=>$d?:$t` (PHP 7), where `$c` is the current char `$d` the previous and `$t` the previous type.
4. See my [PHP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128160/29637). Tomorrow I will award the bounty.

Comment: This is my first question :) [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12770/29637) got two upvotes and no comments so I think its ready to be posted. Feel free to make suggestions !

Comment: What characters can appear in the input?

Comment: @MartinEnder all chars your string supports e.g. even the null byte for `c++` style strings. Think of it as binary data.

Comment: What does `*` mean?

Comment: @LeakyNun `*` means the corresponding suffix is of type `left most s-type`. `A S-type suffix that is preceeded by a L-type suffix.`.

Comment: Can numbers appear in the input? Are they less than other characters? Can we use the ASCII number representation of characters to determine lexicographical order?

Comment: @Luke `"all chars your string supports"`. Uhm of course I should specify the order: Use the byte value to compare strings. I will edit that in thanks !

Comment: Some more test cases might be good. Am I right in thinking the result will always end in an `L`? What should be the result for an empty string as input, or is the input guaranteed to be non-empty?

Comment: @JonathanAllan You are right that the last one has to be `L` type: the following suffix is by definition always smaller so its always larger. Empty input would have an empty output (because there's no suffix that needs a type) but feel free to ignore that case.

Comment: Also, may we output an array of some other type - for example 1 in place of `L`, -1 in place of `S` and 0 in place of `*`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'd like to line up the input string and the type string under each other so I can easily see the type of the char when looking at a given suffix. So please output only a single char for each input char.

Comment: I assume the output will always start with either `L` or `S`?

Comment: @Neil Correct! There is never a L-type suffix in front of the first so there can never be a LMS-type in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>64</strike> <strike>53</strike> <strike>48</strike> 42 bytes

```hs
(0!)
k!(x:y)|x:y>y=1:2!y|2>1=k:0!y
_![]=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyflfraus4OPo5x7q6O6q4BwQoKCsW8vFVWUb81/DQFGTK1tRo8KqUrMGSNhV2hpaGSlW1hjZGdpmWxkoVnLFK0bH2kbH/s9NzMxTsFXITSzwjVfQiClW0LVTKCjKzCtR0CjWAYoqaCgF@2gpKSpqalQpFGtqaipEK@XmZmYWF0NwQUGmko5SBtA9@Qrl@UU5KUCeB5gXDuWZGjsmHVqualoYrBT7HwA)

Ungolfed, with `Char` instead of `Int`:

```hs
suffixes :: String -> String
suffixes = go 'S'
 where
   go :: Char -> String -> String
   go _ "" = ""
   go lorstar s | s > tail s = 'L' : go '*' (tail s)
                | otherwise  = lorstar : go 'S' (tail s)
```

Comment: Anonymous functions are allowed, so the `z=` can be removed.

Comment: I just can't read Haskell. Would you mind giving me a brief explaination?

Comment: @Christoph : the `go` function takes two arguments. The first is the character that represents what should be used to describe the `S` situation. The second is a string. It goes through that string recursively, removing the first character at each step (that's what `tail` does). The trick is that the first argument is set to `*` when the previous result was a `L`, or `S` otherwise. That way, in the case where an `*` or an `S` should be used, that first argument can be used directly. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That's quite a nice idea ! I'm hoping to see more clever ideas :)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen how am I supposed to prepare the result in TIO?

Comment: @bartavelle I haven't found a good way to avoid the `name=` in the TIO code panel, so I just strip it from the post by hand, and other people seem to do the same. If only there was a way to drop the line break after the header...

Comment: There is a standard format for titles in answers, which automated leaderboards rely on, so it's not a good idea to end it with anything not matching "<N> bytes". I really just meant removing the `z=` in the post (and count) altogether. It requires editing the post a bit after preparing it in TIO, but only in two places.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I changed it in the description, but kept the TIO unchanged.

Comment: Oh, nice trick with the CPP in TIO. (Did my quine inspire you?)

Comment: Just had a hindsight, updating all my answers right now! I will look at your quine though!

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>25 23 21 20</s>  19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ṛ;\UỤỤIṠµI2n×ịØDṚ;0
```

A full program that prints the list of characters, using:

```
L: 0
S: 8
*: 9
```

(As a link it returns a list where all items are characters except the last one, which is a zero.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlnWMaEPdy8BIs@HOxcc2upplHd4@sPd3YdnuIAkDf7//6/kAVScrxCeX5STogQA)** or see the [test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlnWMaEPdy8BIs@HOxcc2upplHd4@sPd3YdnuIAkDf4fbn/UMMfAxyLYUutRw9zKfCDhY@0AFNO1UwCyuY7uAapoWuP@/3@0Um5uZmZxMQQXFGQq6SgoZQAtylcozy/KSQFxPcDccBjX1Ngx6dByVdPCYKVYAA) (with conversion to `LS*`).

#### How?

```
Ṛ;\UỤỤIṠµI2n×ịØDṚ;0 - Link: list of characters, s  e.g. "cast"
Ṛ                   - reverse                           "tsac"
  \                 - cumulative reduce by:
 ;                  -   concatenation                   ["t","ts","tsa","tsac"]
   U                - upend (reverse each)              ["t","st","ast","cast"] (suffixes)
    Ụ               - sort indexes by value             [3,4,2,1] (lexicographical order)
     Ụ              - sort indexes by value             [4,3,1,2] (order of that)
      I             - incremental differences           [-1,-2,1] (change)
       Ṡ            - sign                              [-1,-1,1] (comparisons)
        µ           - monadic chain separation, call that x
         I          - incremental differences           [0,2] (only (-1,1) produce 2s)
          2         - literal 2                         2
           n        - not equal?                        [1,0] (indexes of * will be 0)
            ×       - multiply by x (vectorises)        [-1,0,1] (make indexes of *s 0)
              ØD    - decimal yield                     "0123456789"
             ị      - index into (1-indexed & modular)  ['8','9','0']
                Ṛ   - reverse                           ['0','9','8']
                 ;0 - concatenate a zero                ['0','9','8',0]
                    - implicit print                     0980
                    -                              i.e. "L*SL"
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a small explaination for me ?

Comment: I will do of course - I am thinking about possible golfs first...

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9U2yHGxigm9NBWT908Q2vtR407wv4fbn/UtCby//9opdzczMziYgguKMhU0lFQygBqzFcozy/KSQFxPcDccBjX1Ngx6dByVdPCYKVYAA)

Comment: @LeakyNun How did you work that out?! You are using a bug there I think `+` on strings seems to vectorise but the underlying results are not actually Jelly iterables but strings (!) (e.g. try `+@/L€` or `+@/L€€` or ...)

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes, `+` produces actual string. This is an undocumented feature, or what you call bug.

Comment: @LeakyNun You have dropped a character by using pairwise reduction.

Comment: @LeakyNun would you mind explaining your proposal?

Comment: @Christoph I don't know why he hasn't accepted my proposal.

Comment: @LeakyNun because it does not work - it does not have the last character.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>92</s> <s>87</s> <s>74</s> <s>69</s> 65 bytes

```python
s=input()
c=1
while s:d=s<s[1:];print(d+(c<d),end='');s=s[1:];c=d
```

Uses `0` for `L`, `1` for `S`, and `2` for `*`. Wrap the input string in quote characters; I believe this is allowed by convention.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6faKukpPS/2DYzr6C0REOTK9nWkKs8IzMnVaHYKsW22KY42tAq1rqgKDOvRCNFWyPZJkVTJzUvxVZdXdO62BYim2yb8h9oClSfoVVqRWqyRqImVJfm/9zczMziYgguKMjkykjNyclXKM8vyknh8gCzw8FsU2PHpEPLVU0LgwE)

Example use:

```
mmiissiissiippi
002100210021000
```

*saved 5 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun, 4 bytes thanks to ovs*

Comment: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfaKukpPS/2DYzr6C0REOTKxjI50q2NeQqz8jMSVUotkqxLbYpjja0irUO1rZNSNHWSLZJ0UywLraFCCbbpnAVFGXmlSgE/weaBNVmaJVakZqskPhfKTc3M7O4GIILCjKVuJQyUnNy8hXK84tyUoA8DzAvHMozNXZMOrRc1bQwWAkA)

Comment: [This can be shortened to 65 bytes with Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6faKukpPS/2DYzr6C0REOTK9nWkKs8IzMnVaHYKsW22KY42tAq1rqgKDOvRCNFWyPZJkVTJzUvxVZdXdO62BYim2yb8h9oClSfoVVqRWqyRqImVJfm/9zczMziYgguKMjkykjNyclXKM8vyknh8gCzw8FsU2PHpEPLVU0LgwE)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>51</s> 45 bytes

```
f=(c,d)=>c&&(d<(d=c<(c=c.slice(1))))+d+f(c,d)
```

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Neil.*

A recursive solution to the exercise.

```js
f=(c,d)=>c&&(d<(d=c<(c=c.slice(1))))+d+f(c,d)

console.log(f('mmiissiissiippi')); //LL*SLL*SLL*SLLL   002100210021000
console.log(f('hello world'));     //L*SSL*L*LLL       02110202000
console.log(f('Hello World'));     //SSSSL*SSLLL       11110211000
console.log(f('53Ab§%5qS'));       //L*SSL*SLL         021102100
```

Comment: Save 6 bytes: `f=(c,d)=>c&&(d<(d=c<(c=c.slice(1))))+d+f(c,d)`

Comment: Thanks, @Neil, I *knew* there had to be an optimization in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/./g,_=>(c<(c=s<(s=s.slice(1))))+c,c=1)
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Port of @L3viathan's answer.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Oops, somehow I managed to port `c=1` as `c=0`...

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 70 bytes

L = 1, S = 0 , * = 2

Multibyte Support is needed for the last Testcase with the `§` +3 Bytes `mb_substr` instead `substr`

```php
for(;$s=&$argn;$s=$u)$r.=$l=($l&1)+(1&$l^($s>$u=substr($s,1)));echo$r;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/NasMwEITvfgqjLkZKnILPipNDCLQgmoMKPfQnOI4aGRRJrGx6CM1b5@zKaqEsw@wy32HWaz8u1177TCE63KPyDvvOnuh1u3/aPT9utoxnnw5V02r6Ss7nrgvhV953pMzvciFm8l8iI1oZ4/Ivh@aYgMUqJzGTYhZHCJKRh0S8JOIPkHICpEzAexOgwZNll8EG1VPAEgzjYyxCOYS6SOm0wcAA72swNQVTVGxOqwLMB4WwgqEOwyH0GI@yYoxx1WoHyMfJyZsl/Hu8Wbdo42/qBw)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 71 bytes

L = 1, S = 0 , * = 2

```php
for(;$s=&$argn;$s=$u)$r.=+($s>$u=substr($s,1));echo strtr($r,[10=>12]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Bi8IwEIXv/RUhG5ZEq1iv2daDCArBPUTwoCLdbjSFmoRJiwfZ/deea1oPIsODefM@hhmnXfs1c9pFCsDCEZSzUJfmTP8Xx/X3ZjVfMB6dLKi80HSHL5ey9P4p50ocow8kxEC@JCKsVVVZdLVQ/fbAKEM4ZFIMQgmBI7zsie0bIWVHSNkTh9yTHM6G3RrjVU0JMN6GMygnPv3so64jDSMwToeU@Iw0qW9@fA3BxAljXBXaouC7CcS7ZJJmyfQQ9nQB3hvM/9q7saMivKYe)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 74 bytes

```php
for(;$s=&$argn;$s=$u)$r.=SL[$s>$u=substr($s,1)];echo strtr($r,[LS=>"L*"]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Ba8MwDIXv@RVGM8Mu6WBnL9lhFFow3cGDHbJQ0tSrA6ltpIQexvavd86c7DCGeCDpfYin6OL08BhdzCxiwAPaGHDo/Fl8bQ7755fd00aq7D2gbVonKrhcuo7oVzF2kLMbpvXK/Eln4GzfB3YN2J8WYF0ySJ7Rq1RaQwbbhXj9RxgzE8YsRN0Qb/Ds5cfoyQ6Co1RTiiEUp@J2seaOj5LjXWF0xankY0HjkQYUnPJ7WSvbusDSPG8wr7QpypQD6nRqtuDNg/qcvn1Yt@k7@wM)

Comment: `$s=&$argn` quite clever ! I'm pretty sure there is a better answer though ;) Hopefully someone comes up with it :)

Comment: @Christoph I have the feeling that I am miss something. I have try to store the last LS* in a varibale but it is longer

Comment: @Christoph mean you like so? I coul not really seen why the last testcase is false [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BSsQwEEDv/YoSx5KsXaHInmJXRBYUgh6y4MFdl26Nm0I2iZMWD6K/43/4T55r2j2oDMPM8B7DjNe@P7/w2icK0eEGlXfYNnZHPxab27vlzdWC8eTZoapqTR/Ift80IRzS@4bk6VEqxET@pkiIVsa49NWheRqF6TwlkUkxiSEEScj1aNz/M6QcDCkPxuzscvv1eTx7kSTy9M8OOfB1FaDCnWVvnQ2qpYA5GMb7eCnlEMpspEMHHQM8LcGUFExWsBNaZGAeKYQ5dGXotqHFOOQFY4yrWjtA3g@VrCzh7/23ddM6Pq9@AA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @Christoph Okay I have seen it why it not works for the last testcase I must use `mb_substr` instead of `substr` if the input is not in the simple ascii range. Is it necessary to support the last testcase?

Comment: I consider single byte values the default string type in PHP. That means you don't need to support multibyte chars.

Comment: @Christoph Thank You In this case I ignore the last testcase with the `§`

Comment: @Christoph mean you for example `for(;~$c=$argn[-++$i];$l=$c)$r=($c<=>$l?$c>$l?1:0:$r[0]).$r;echo str_replace("10","12",$r);` this with a backward iteration?

Comment: I was sure ` strtr` wouldn't go unnoticed :D

Comment: @Christoph I have not thinking about this. It helps not really cause I have found a shorter way without it. And I have compare measuring microtime my shortest way with yours. So I do not understand what you mean with two parallel forward iterations

Comment: My linear time version does a single pass over the input from the back to the front. But it can be done a bit more complicated by basically two interleaved for loops but its a bit hard to explain without code and I don't have the code for it anymore because it was a bit slower than the single backward iteration.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>77</s> 75 bytes, linear time

```hs
f(a:b:c)|let g"L"|a<b="SL";g"S"|a>b="L*";g d=d++d;d:e=f$b:c=g[d]++e
f _="L"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY6xCsIwGIT3PsVPqKAGXKRLawQ3h24ZHEQkbZI2mKS1ibj0fXwPXyz@1OG4@@AOrhfhoaxNSa9F2ZTtZrYqQkdqMotDwwivSdURjnREqrdIIJmkVFayVEznuGHdVd4oVZmGO3ZIcsJ4YGB8VJNoI@Tw8tZ4FWAHToyg0RdOzhkTwl/jaLIevwzwHiYrs/OSL0su9qfm@1kVT/4D)

#### How it works

This uses recursion, stripping off one character at a time from the beginning of the string.  (The Haskell string type is a singly-linked list of characters, so each of these steps is constant-time.)

- For a string *abc* where *a* and *b* are single characters and *c* is any (possibly empty) string,

  - *f*(*abc*) = SL*e*, if *f*(*bc*) = L*e* and *a* < *b*;
  - *f*(*abc*) = L**e*, if *f*(*bc*) = S*e* and *a* > *b*;
  - *f*(*abc*) = LL*e*, if *f*(*bc*) = L*e* and *a* ≥ *b*;
  - *f*(*abc*) = SS*e*, if *f*(*bc*) = S*e* and *a* ≤ *b*.
- For a single-character string *a*, *f*(*a*) = L.

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation?

Comment: Please provide a description so I can validate that this runs in linear time.

Comment: @Christoph Added.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg thanks for adding ! Sadly this seems quite verbose compared to the other Haskell answer. Could this be golfed further by not using `S, L and *`?

Comment: @Christoph The other Haskell answer is quadratic, and also returns output as a list like `[1,1,2,0,1,1,2,0,1,1,2,0,1,1,1]`, which seems to violate your requirement to “output only a single char for each input char”.

Comment: Seems I wrongly assumed it outputs a string. Thanks for notifying me ! In order to not invalidate the top rated answer I will allow to return a list of single chars. Does this improve your answer ?

Comment: @Christoph To be clear, `[1,1,2,0,1,1,2,0,1,1,2,0,1,1,1]` is a list of single-digit numbers, not a list of single chars. In my case, I think outputting a list of numbers would not save me any bytes.

Comment: Sadly (for me) no competition on the linear time version :( Anyway congratulation on winning the bounty !

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 88 bytes

```c
S(S,A,I)char*S,*A;{for(;strlen(S);A=S,S++,printf("%c",I=strcmp(A,S)>0?76:I==76?42:83));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcq9CoMwFEDhuT6FBAqJRiht0WJIJaPzfYJwqzVgfojSRXzszqnQ4UzfwQpn7d4pAQWueM9w0rEAXiixjT5SsaxxHhwFJpQEDmXJQzRuHSk5I@G9PBxtoIoDe166pm57KZu6u1/bx40xsadjzq02jn68ebF8y05AibXGLMu/EAxhItvT1/kKNU7DDw)

Comment: [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P1gjWMdRx1MzOSOxSCtYR8vRujotv0jDurikKCc1TyNY07qgtAQkqeFpCxRLzi3QcNQJ1rQzsDc3s/LUNTeztzC2MjHS1HS0DdbWtq79n5lXopCbmJmnUZafmaKpUM3FGayhlJubmVlcDMEFBZlKmtZctf8B "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>65</s> 55 bytes

Recursive version, based on [L3viathan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126101/38592), using `012` as `LS*`:

```python
def g(s,d=2):c=s<s[1:];return s and`c+(d<c)`+g(s[1:],c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFdo1gnxdZI0yrZttimONrQKta6KLWktChPoVghMS8lIVlbI8UmWTNBG6gQJKuTrPm/PCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRCNdIzOvoLREQ1NT879Sbm5mZnExBBcUZCpxKWWk5uTkK5TnF@WkAHkeYF44lGdq7Jh0aLmqaWGwEgA)

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>65</s> 59 bytes

Recursive solution using `L`, `S`, and `*`:

```python
f=lambda s:s and('LS'[s<s[1:]]+f(s[1:])).replace('LS','L*')
```

Runs through the string from the front, and replaces all instances of `LS`with `L*`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRodiqWCExL0VD3SdYPbrYpjja0Co2VjtNA8zQ1NQrSi3ISUxOBcvrqPtoqWv@L8/IzElVMLQqKMrMK9FI08jMKygt0dDU1Pyfm5uZWVwMwQUFmVwZqTk5@Qrl@UU5KVweYHY4mG1q7Jh0aLmqaWEwAA)

Comment: `blah if s else''` → `s and blah` saves six bytes. In Python 2, `str(blah)` → `\`blah\`` saves another three bytes on the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 82 byte, linear time

```
for($a=$argn;a&$c=$a[$i-=1];$d=$c)$a[$i]=2+$t=$d<=>$c?:$t;echo strtr($a,[13=>12]);
```

Walks over the input from right to left and replaces each char with the type.

```
$t=$d<=>$c?:$t
```

Calculates the type given the current and the previous char (-1 or 1). If equal the type doesn't change.

Comment: +1 for the idea with `strtr`